# Bash script which open multiple tabs gnome terminal, help write

Tags: bash, terminal

Help me write bash script which open multiple tabs gnome terminal, please.
I have seen error message for this script.

> Failed to parse arguments: Argument to "--command/-e" is not a valid
>   command: Text ended before matching quote was found for '. (The text
>   was ''ssh')

Regards,

```
#bin/bash
# Open a terminal to each of the servers
#
# The list of servers
LIST="server01.com server02.com server03.com"
KEYRSA="rsa.key"
KEYDSS="dss.key"
USERLOGIN="username"
RUNONSERVER="sudo -s"

for WWW in $LIST
do
    TITLE=`echo -n "${s}" | sed 's/^\(.\)/\U\1/'`
    #RUNCMD="--tab --title=${TITLE} --command ssh -t -i ${KEYDSS} ${USERLOGIN}@${WWW} ${RUNONSERVER}"
    RUNCMD="--tab --title=${TITLE} -e 'ssh -t -i ${KEYDSS} ${USERLOGIN}@${WWW} ${RUNONSERVER}'"
done

    gnome-terminal --geometry=120x50+500+100 ${RUNCMD}

exit 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, read up on [how to put a command in a variable](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050). Then, if you add `set -o xtrace` to the top of your file you can see which command is actually being executed in the loop. You'll want the final command to have only *syntactic* [quotes](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes), not *literal* ones.

Some more generally applicable tips:

- Use [arrays](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/Arrays) rather than strings for lists of things
- [Use `$(my_command)` syntax for command substitution](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/126928/3645)
- Uppercase variable names are by convention for variables which are [exported](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/InputAndOutput#The_Environment).